# ADODB Connection to upload data to SQL using bind variables

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, ado

I'm trying to upload some data into a SQL database from a spreadsheet. I'm Using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271105/excel-vba-sql-query-and-field-mappings/34273330#34273330) as a base, had to make a few mods in order to get it to work.

```vb
Sub newtest()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim cs As String
Dim C1, C2, C3, C4 As String
Dim RowNo As Long
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim strFile As Variant
    Dim shtname As String
    ChDir "xxxxxx"
    strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If strFile = False Then
    Exit Sub
    Else: End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

cs = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;User ID=xxx; Password=xxxxxx; "

conn.ConnectionString = cs

conn.Open


' *** Open workbooks first ***
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFile)
shtname = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name
lastrow = wbk.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
With Sheets(shtname)

cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "insert into EcommerceXRefMapping_C_Copy values (@EquivalentPartNumber_C, @Manufacturer_C, @CatamacPartNumber_C, @Notes_C)"
cmd.NamedParameters = True

 'Skip the header row
        RowNo = 2

        'Loop until empty cell in Col 1
        Do Until .Cells(RowNo, 1) = ""
            i = i + 1
            C1 = .Cells(RowNo, 1)
            C2 = .Cells(RowNo, 2)
            C3 = .Cells(RowNo, 3)
            C4 = .Cells(RowNo, 4)

            'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table

            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@EquivalentPartNumber_C", adVarChar, adParamInput, 256, C1)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Manufacturer_C", adVarChar, adParamInput, 256, C2)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@CatamacPartNumber_C", adVarChar, adParamInput, 256, C3)
            cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Notes_C", adVarChar, adParamInput, 256, C4)

            cmd.Execute

            RowNo = RowNo + 1
        Loop

End With

        wbk.Close
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I'm getting an error when trying to execute

```
cmd.execute
```

The error message is

```
Run-time error'-2147217800 (80040e14)':
Must declare the scalar variable "@EquivalentPartNumber_C".
```

Any ideas how to fix? I thought that the declaring of the variables was done with the "@" character? Sorry, I'm quite new to VBA so please bear with me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you mix notation for `stored procedure` and `text` type of command but...

1. you can omit `@` when passing parameters
2. you should add `cmd.CommandType = adCmdText` right after your `cmdCommandText` line
3. I would change SQL query into:

`"insert into EcommerceXRefMapping_C_Copy values (?, ?, ?, ?)"`

and next pass parameters in this way (where correct order is important):

```
cmd.Parameters(0) = c1
cmd.Parameters(1) = c2
cmd.Parameters(2) = c3
cmd.Parameters(3) = c4
```

Comment: Cmd.Type  gives error "Method or data member not found" ??  If I omit that, i get the error "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition" ?

Comment: Should mention that there are other columns in this table, it is only these 4 columns that I am wanting to insert data into.

Comment: so, in fact you have wrong sql statement. See [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) and change as required

Comment: one more thing, instead of `cmd.Type = adCmdText` you should use `cmd.CommandType = adCmdText`